# MATLAB loop-index issue

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, for-loop, indexing

Context: I must create a program that describes the motion of a car being tested for a quarter-mile time as part of a performance analysis. This involves time, distance, velocity, acceleration, forces, torque, and rotational speed.

In the last for loop I get the following error with whatever line of code is at the top (in this example the engine torque):

> "Attempted to access RPM(2); index out of bounds because numel(RPM)=1."

```
clear all
close all
clc

time(1) = 0; %[seconds]
dist(1) = 0;
vel(1) = 0;
accel(1) = 0;

RPMmin = 1200;
RPM(1) = RPMmin;
r = 19; %[inches]
wt = 3760; %[pounds]

Ng = [3.253, 2.233, 1.611, 1.243, 1, 0.629]; %{Gear Ratio}
Nd = [3.73]; %differential ratio
dt = 0.1; %time increment 

for k = 1:1:6

    xntt(k) = Ng(k) * Nd;
    xmf(k) = 1 + (0.04 * xntt(k)) + (0.0025 * xntt(k)^2);
    gst = 0.25; %gear shift time

end

for i = 1:1:1000

  Te(i) = 18.154 + (.1571 * RPM(i)) - (0.0000147 * (RPM(i))^2);
  fx(i) = Te(i) * xntt(k)/(r/12);
  dV(i + 1) = (32.2/(wt * xmf(k)))*fx(i);
  accel(i + 1) = dV(i)/dt;
  vel(i + 1) = vel(i) + (dV(i) * dt);
  dist(i + 1) = dist(i) + vel(i + 1)*dt;
  time(i + 1) = time(i) + dt;
  RPM(i) = (vel(i + 1)*60*xntt(k))/((2*pi*r)/12);

end
```

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory... You're trying to access `RPM(i)` before it is defined. If you look at your code you'll see that you are defining `RPM` for loop iteration `i`, not `i + 1`.

Comment: @excaza as always, error messages are self explanatory :)

Comment: @dnit13 not always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when `i=2` inside the for-loop (second iteration). Depending on `RPM`, you basically have two choices:

- let `Te(i)` depend on `RPM(i-1)`, so `Te(2)` will depend on `RPM(1)` and so on. This will, however, throw an error when `i=1` due to the fact that if `i=1`, then `i-1=0` and Matlab allows only positive indices so you need to place an `if` check inside the loop.
- let `RPM` grow just like `Te`, so if at iteration `i` you're writing on `Te(i+1)`, write as well on `RPM(i+1)`.

Both of these approaches lead to a code with no errors (i.e. syntactically correct) but then you must choose the correct approach depending on what your problem is and how such vectors are sort of "linked" together (i.e. your code must be semantically correct as well).